# How to find the finite or infinite sum of a given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider $k$ with $\frac 12≤ k < 1$

Define the set $A = \{k^n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$

How can we prove that if $x\in (0,1)$ then there is a finite or infinite sum of the numbers in A (repetitions not permitted) which equals x.

The only way I can think of is using $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty  k^i = \frac{k}{1-k}$$
But I guess this doesn't cover all numbers in $(0,1)$

Comment: This is not clear.  What is $A$?  Is it $\{k, k^2, \cdots, k^n\}$?

Comment: Neither is your question clear.  Since $A$ (whatever it means) is finite then there are only finitely many $x$ that can be written as sums from $A$ without repetition.

Comment: A is a sequence. The summation of sum or all the elements in A should equal a number x = (0,1).  How can I prove that ?

Comment: Oh, so $A$ consists of $\{k^n\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$?  Would that have been so hard to say?   For instance, with $k=\frac 12$, this is just the base $2$ representation of a number between $0$ and $1$, yes?

Comment: If you know how to prove that any $x$ has a base $2$ representation, I expect that the same argument works here.  At each stage, just subtract the largest power of $k$ you can.  Since $\sum k^n>1$  you can always get $x$ back.

Comment: So, go through the proof that every number has a base $2$ representation (this is not a triviality).  Try to adapt it to your $k$,.  I think the greedy algorithm should work (just take out the biggest $k^n$ you can at each stage), but it needs to be written out to be sure.

Comment: Just to stress: the greedy algorithm does not always work.  You can't, say, do this with $k=\frac 13$.  That's because $\sum \left( \frac 13 \right)^n<1$.  That's why the base $3$ representation requires repetitions.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out so far but the basic idea is how to represent any decimal number (0,1) using infinite or finite sum of  k^n

Comment: Yes, that's right.   As I say, with $k=\frac 12$ this is just the usual binary expansion.  Thus, $\frac 13=.\overline {01}_2$, for example.  My claim (which I have not proven and which might be wrong) is that you can do this algorithmically.  For each $x\in (0,1)$ let $x_1=k^i$ where $i\in \mathbb N$ is defined so that $k^i≤x<k^{i-1}$.  Then let $x_n$ be defined similarly (take out the largest power of $k$ that does not exceed $x-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x_{j}$.  I claim (again, possibly in error) that the exponents you get are all distinct and increasing and that $x=\sum x_n$.

Comment: I have sketched the solution below.  Barring error (always possible, so be sure to check) it seems to work out along the lines I had suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:  choose $x\in (0,1)$.  Let $x_1=k^i$ where $i=i_1\in \mathbb N$ such that $$k^i≤x< k^{i-1}$$  Similarly define $x_n=x^{i_n}$ where $i_n\in \mathbb N $is such that $$k^{i_n}≤x-\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}x_{l}< k^{i_n-1}$$

Claim 1:  The exponents $\{i_j\}$ are strictly increasing.

Pf:  It is enough to show that $i_1<i_2$.  But suppose otherwise. Then we must have $$x-k^{i_1}≥k^{i_1}$$   But $$x-k^{i_1}≥k^{i_1}\implies x≥2k^{i_1}≥\frac 1k k^{i_1}=k^{i_1-1}$$ a contradiction.

Note:  this is where we have used the fact that $k≥\frac 12$.  Indeed, the desired result is false without this.

Claim 2:  $$x=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}x_l$$

Pf:  Let $S$ denote that sum.  Clearly the sum converges so $S$ is some real value. Let $S_n$ denote the partial sums.  By definition, $x-S_n≥0$ for each $n$ so $S$ can not exceed $x$.  Suppose $S<x$.  Then there is some $k^{i_*}< x-S$.  But at some point all the $i_l>i_*$  This is absurd, as clearly at any stage we could have subtracted $k^{i_*}$ .  Thus $S=x$ and we are done.